# Global variable jsp servlets

Tags: jsp, servlets, global-variables

I've got 2 jsp files (index and go) and 1 java class MyClass. In index.jsp I've got an instance of MyClass. I want to use this same instance in go.jsp file. How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Are you familiar with scopes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In index.jsp use ->

```
application.setAttribute("myclass" , new MyClass());
```

in go.jsp use ->

```
MyClass myclass = (MyClass)application.getAttribute("myclass");
```

In the above code `application` is a application level variable , you can access it from all the jsp's and servlets.